# How can I add advertisement script inside yii framework loop?

Tags: javascript, php, yii, ads

I am trying to add an horizontal ad in between the content. An example article of my website is: http://articlefirm.com/biography/penny-taylor-age-net-worth-biography-twitter.html. I would like the ad to come somewhere inside the content.

The website is on YII framework. Here's the content code:

```
<?php echo $page->detail; ?>
```

Please let me know how could I add script inside the above given code.

Comment: You can add  in view  or in template .. but the code you provided is not enough ..

Comment: @scaisEdge, I have a view - main.php calling `<?php echo $content; ?>`

Comment: you are using yii1 or yii2?

Comment: The website is using yii1.

Comment: then main.php is the layout  .. .. you have the standard  main.php layout or you have alrady modified ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can change your main.php layout and add  the code for show the ads as you like  this way

if you need  pass some php vars to the main.php layout

a simple way is add  property to your controller

```
 class YourController extends CController {

    public $myParam;
```

then assign in your action the values you need  for params

eg:

```
 $this->myParam ='my_adv';
```

and then in your layout you can simple

```
<?php echo $this->myParam; ?>
```

otherwise if you don't need pass params form controller/action

you can simply change you views/layouts/main.php

adding the conde you need

```
<?php 

  echo 'here i cand add  the adv i need before the view content'; 
?>

<?php echo $content; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks @scaisEdge. I will try this.